# Dúvida em Struct + Ponteiro em C

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct

Considerando o código abaixo, gostaria de saber porque o segundo printF do procedimento LeAluno não imprime corretamente?

```
#define MAX 3
typedef struct aluno{
    int matricula;
    float notas[2];
} Aluno ;
int t=1;
void LeAluno(Aluno *Param){// com ponteiro
    t++;
    Param->matricula=10*t;
    Param->notas[0]=20*t;
    printf("\n 1   %f",(*Param).notas[0]);
    printf("\n 2   %f",*(Param+sizeof(int)) ); //size of int matricula;
    Param->notas[1]=30*t;
}
void main(){
    int i;
    Aluno Turma[MAX];
    for(i=0; i< MAX; i++)
        LeAluno(&Turma[i]); 
}
```

Comment: Os printfs são:  printf("\n 1  %f",(*Param).notas[0]);
printf("\n 2  %f",*(Param+sizeof(int)) );

Comment: Explique o que quer mostrar com os prints

Comment: Para aceder a membros duma estrutura através dum ponteiro podes usar o atalho `->` -- `(*Param).notas[0]` é o mesmo que `Param->notas[0]`

Answer (score 1):

Até agora não entendi o que quis fazer com

`printf("\n 2   %f",*(Param+sizeof(int)) ); //size of int matricula;`

Mas se substituir por isso, terá a matrícula:

`printf("\n 2   %d",(*Param).matricula );`

Repare que a matricula é `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Se entendi direito, você está querendo que o segundo printf tenha o mesmo resultado do primeiro printf.

Como Param é uma struct de 12 elementos, quando você faz uma [aritmética de ponteiro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/25ckw473.aspx), para cada unidade que você soma, você soma 12 elementos. Portanto, na verdade você estava somando 48 posições (12*`sizeof(int)`).

Então, para executar corretamente, você tem que transformar essa struct de 12 elementos em um ponteiro para char, que possui 1 byte. E para utilizar o printf como float, você tem que, após a aritmetica com ponteiro, transformar o ponteiro para char em ponteiro para float.

Fica assim:

```
printf("\n 2   %f",*(float *)((char *)Param+sizeof(int)) ); //size of int matricula;
```